# LPL ( language proof and logic) - FITCH - 14.12

Tags: logic, fitch

what's wrong with the last line in my proof? i can't understand the error on line 21
[image]

i wrote the important line of the proof :

18 - `∀z (Cube(z) → (z = c ∨ z = f))`

19 - `∃y (Cube(c) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ c ≠ y)`

20 - `∃y (Cube(c) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ c ≠ y) ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = c ∨ z = f))`

21 - `∃x ∃y (Cube(x) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ x ≠ y ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y)))`

**EDIT**

NOW IT WORK BUT I CAN'T USE FO CON. **HOW CAN I WROTE THE SAME LINE WITHOUT USE FO CON?**

[image]

Comment: 21 has an existential quant more than 20: this need a new ∃-intro...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  
i tried but it doesn't work. can you tell me what line i have to select?

Comment: From 20 to 21 the z=f has been rewritten as z=y. Whu ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it's a mine error because the ∃-quant doesn't take the  ∀z part. How can include the ∀z(..) inside the  ∃ intro in the line 20?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

18 - ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = c ∨ z = f))

19 - (Cube(c) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ c ≠ y) ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = c ∨ z = f)) --- from 4 and 18 by ∧-intro

20 - ∃x ∃y [(Cube(x) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ x ≠ y) ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y))] --- from 19 by ∃-intro twice

20 is derived under the two assumptions 3 and 4 made for two ∃-elim's with terms c and f. They are not present in 20; thus, we can safely conclude with 20 by ∃-elim twice, discharging temporary assumptions 3 and 4.

Conclusion:

> 1, 2 ⊢ ∃x ∃y [(Cube(x) ∧ Cube(y) ∧ x ≠ y) ∧ ∀z (Cube(z) → (z = x ∨ z = y))]